# Android undefined is not an object evaluating custom module - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, npm

I am trying to learn how to write a react-native module, and I am getting stuck with this error:

[image]

Here is what my code looks like:

#### Module.java (../android/src/main/java/com/reactlibrary)

```
public class RNGifMakerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  public RNGifMakerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "RNGifMaker";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void alert(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

#### index.android.js

```
import { RNGifMaker } from 'GifMaker';

const onButtonPress = () => {
 RNGifMaker.alert('Hello World');
};
```

#### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.43.3",
    "GifMaker":"file:../"
},
```

#### index.js (../)

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

module.exports = NativeModules.RNGifMaker;
```

I have run both `npm install` and `react-native link`.

I have (for the most part) followed [this tutorial](http://www.codepool.biz/react-native-bridging-modules-android.html).

Comment: Is RNGifMaker supposed to originate from NativeModules in file react-native.js or from a file called GifMaker.js?

Comment: It is supposed to originate form `../index.js`

Comment: Then why import from GifMaker.js instead of from index.js in index.androud.js?

Comment: GifMaker.js does not exist. I am importing it form `GifMaker` which I set in `package.json`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! In `Module.java` I was returning the wrong class.

Was:

```
public String getName() {
    return "RNGifMaker";
}
```

Should have been:

```
 public String getName() {
    return "RNGifMakerModule";
  }
```